# Canon Rebel t4i shutter stuck

Tags: canon, shutter

I have a Canon Rebel T4i. The last two photo shoots, the shutter almost sounds stuck. It goes off very very slowly. The battery is fully charged. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Are you in bulb mode? Are images ok?

Comment: Are you in low light with a small aperture (high f/-number) such that the metering results in a long shutter time?